# PHP exec() command works flawlessly in code, but not when called by AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, exec

This command works great if I call it during page execution

```
        exec('run.exe -something', $response, $status);
```

But I have a button on the page that executes the same command via AJAX:

```
                // Attempt a call to change the password
            $.ajax({
                url: 'actions/runcommand.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { 
                    cid: cid, 
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(msg)
                {
                    if (ajaxErr(msg) return;

                    // Show success message
                    showMsg('success!');

                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ajaxFail(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)}
            });
```

I've verified the two are executing literally the same string whether I do it in my code or via the AJAX, but the AJAX initiated one is returning an error code instead of functioning. The value of status is 1 which is a generic error so I have little to go on.

I looked around and found one similar post, but they solved it by removing https from the ajax command. If I do that the browser blocks it with scary messages.

This is running on a local machine which attempts HTTPS but fails because it's a self-signed cert or something. I turned off https redirection for the site, but that made zero difference. Not sure what it's unhappy about... please help!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (ajaxErr(msg) return;
```

Error handling shouldn't be done in the success callback function. You can remove this or modify what this function is doing.

If you're requesting the URL from a different directory, make sure your URL parameter uses a leading slash for the root directory:

```
url: '/actions/runcommand.php',
```

Try this and see if there's still a generic error:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/actions/runcommand.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { 
        cid: cid, 
    },
    dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data, status) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(status);
        showMsg('success!');
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        ajaxFail(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    }
});
```

Comment: I used the whole path, http and HTTPS included (tried both). Neither made any difference (minus a mixed content warning). The ajaxerr is just a way for me to handle my own error correction in the file and is unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok folks, this had all the signs of a boneheaded mistake and that's what it was. I'm leaving it here for posterity because it's an easy mistake to make and I saw other people ask similar questions with no good answer.

The SOLUTION was that my AJAX files were in a SUBDIRECTORY and that means when they executed the command the output which was trying to export to a subdir of the root was trying to find that subdir in ANOTHER SUBDIR. Sheesh!